# How can I run function after .addClass?

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have a jQuery plugin that adds and removes a class to `<li>` elements. Can I add a listener to `<li>` elements that runs a function after a class is added?

Here is the example:

```
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li class="actual">item 3</li>
   <li>item 4</li>
   <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

The `actual` class is moved by the plugin.

Comment: Does the plugin raise an event in the process which adds the class? Which plugin is it

Comment: What plugin is it? Is there an event or callback you can use in the plugin to know when the change has occurred?

Comment: This is the Roundabout plugin http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Comment: ...anyway not the plugin name is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you are using does trigger events you can hook to. See http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout#events

```
$('ul').on('reposition', function(){
 // do what you want with $('li.actual')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you can use this plugin to hook to jquery actions:

https://github.com/aheckmann/jquery.hook

Comment: looking good, but if there is a simpler way (without another new plugin) I will choose it. ;)

Comment: The plugin you are using does trigger an event called 'reposition' after the animation completes.

Comment: This method will work regardless of who fires the change (plugin, not plugin, etc.)

Comment: Agreed. Good solution if the `actual` class might be changed in his jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add listener/event after adding class by .addClass() using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event.
For example:

```
$('li:first').addClass('selected');

$('ul').on('click', '.selected', function(e) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

you also can modify the sample.

**Try demo at http://jsfiddle.net/aQsMm/**

Comment: OPs code does not add the class, the plugin does. OP wants to be able to capture that event not fired by OPs code